# Запись в таблицу laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel начал учить совсем недавно, и пока не очень понятно как добавлять данные в таблицу. Вот что в контроллере:

```
public function admin(){

    $add_event = new Add_Event();

    if (Request::has('Title')) {
        if($add_event->add_to_base()){
            $add_event->fill(Request::all());
        }else{
        }
    }
    return view('Admins');
}
```

Вот что в моделе:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Add_Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'All_Events';
    protected $fillable = array('Title', 'Description','Location');

    public function add_to_base(){

        return $this->save();
    }
}
```

В уроках ребята используют Input::, но, как я понял, его выпилили уже.

Comment: Какой laravel? 5.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какой laravel? 5.x?

В 5 для сохранения объекта в базу достаточно просто вызвать метод save() у этого объекта.

```
$add_event->save();
```

P.S. Именуйте классы в стиле `StudlyCaps` а переменные в `camelCase` и не используйте в коде `snake_case`.

Почитайте [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)